# System.Net, cannot resolve symbol 'Net'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, nuget, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

I'm lost. My .NET Framework 4.6.2 cannot resolve my using System.Net. I've added the assembly reference, but is has that yellow warning triangle on the reference. How did I mess this up?

Because of other dependencies I'm stuck with 4.6.2

Comment: Have you ensured .NET Framework 4.6.2 has been installed on your machine? Download it from Microsoft's website

Comment: Paste here your csproj file.

Comment: Can you share the yellow warning message with us or share the whole `xxx.csproj` file with us ?

Answer (score 1):

> I'm lost. My .NET Framework 4.6.2 cannot resolve my using System.Net.
> I've added the assembly reference, but is has that yellow warning
> triangle on the reference. How did I mess this up?

**First**, try to install Net Framework 4.6.2 Developer Pack from [this link](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-framework/net462) or [do a repair in VS Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) in case your `net framework 4.6.2` is broken.

**1)** make sure that Target Framework is 4.6.2 by Right-click on your project--> Properties-->Application-->Target Framework is `net framework 4.6.2`.

**2)** run `update-package -reinstall` under `Tools`-->`Nuget Package Manger`-->`Package Manager Console` to reinstall these nuget packages and their dependencies in case there are in a mess before.

**3)** close VS Instance, delete `bin` and `obj` folder and then restart your project.

**4)** Actually, system.net dll is a system dll of Net Framework and when you use it, you should search under `net framework 4.6.2`.

Right-click on Reference-->Add Reference-->choose the `v4.6.2 System.Net dll`.

[image]

Or go through the path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\System.Net.dll`.

**Actually**, `System.Net` is a part of `System.dll`. And if you have `System.dll` in your project, you can just using `System.Net` in code editor without referencing it again.

**In addition**, you can enter **Error list window**, the warning will be listed in that window and it will tell you what is specific problem and if necessary, you can share it with us.

Comment: `update-package -reinstall` command did it for me. Thanks.